# Flutter card setting with List of generic type

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using card settings inside form. This piece of of code was working fine in the previous version of flutter. My current version of flutter is 1.20.4.

```
            key: _formKeyValue,
            autovalidate: true,
            child: CardSettings(
              children: <Widget>
              [
                MyCardSettingsHeader(
                  label: 'Add Listing',
                ),
              ])
     )
```

When I hover 'children: ' in VSCODE. It gives the following error:

```sh
'List<Widget>' isn't of expected type 'List<CardSettingsSection>'
The list's type can be changed with an explicit generic type argument 
or by changing the element types.dart(invalid_cast_literal_list)"
```

Comment: Did you create your MyCardSettingsHeader as stateless or statefull widget?

Comment: +Alperen its stateless

Comment: +pskink not working

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear. Your widget expects children to be a list of `CardSettingsSection`, but you explicitly pass a list of Widget.

As a first step, remove the `<Widget>`, it's not necessary anyway.

If it does not compile then, you need to look into your `MyCardSettingsHeader` and find out why it does not inherit (or maybe implements? This libraries naming structure is a mess) from `CardSettingsSection`.

Answer (score 0):

u can delete  from your code ; or replace it with